# How do I do a terms aggregation by concatenating two arrays?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch mapping that looks like this:

```
"product": {
  "properties": {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "normalizer": "lowercase"
    },
    "skus": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "attributes": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "normalizer": "lowercase"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to do a terms aggregation on both the field `attributes` and the field `skus.attributes` by concatenating them but I haven't figured out how. Both fields are simple string arrays. This is as far as I've gotten:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggregations": {
      "unique_attrs": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "attributes"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Of course, I could reindex my data in a way that there would be another field that contains a concatenation of the values of both fields but that seem right.

Comment: Without creating a copy you will have to do this using Script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned on the Elasticsearch Forums: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/combining-nested-and-non-nested-aggregations/82583 it recommends merging them using a `copy_to` mapping when indexing the data.